# Getting the right formatting for my XML data

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am wondering why I'm not getting the right XML format when I'm writing my XML answer into a file.

Basically what I'm doing is sending a post request and receiving XML data back, doing something like this:

```
    post_request = s.post('myurl')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(post_request.text, features='xml')
    print(soup2.encode('utf-8')) 

    f=open("exit.xml","w")
    f.write(str(soup2.encode('utf-8')))
    f.close
```

First part does the work correctly but when I write it in my `exit.xml` all the data appears in the wrong format. What I mean by that is that everything is following, there is no indentation. Instead of going to the next line, there is `\n` between the data. I'm getting something like that:

```
<part number="1976">\n<name>Windscreen Wiper</name>\n<description>The Windscreen wiper automatically removes rain from your windscreen, if it should happen to splash there. It has a rubber\n <ref part="1977">blade</ref>\n which can be ordered separately if you need to replace it </description>\n </part>\n
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `b` flag when you open your file for writing. Also, remove the `str(...)`:

```py
with open('exit.xml', 'wb') as f_out:  # <-- add 'b' flag (binary)
    f_out.write(soup2.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: It now goes to the line after each "\n" but it does not indent correctly after. Probably has to do with the response of my request so will check into that. Thank you for your help on that !